# Background process stops when another page is open in phonegap android

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, background-service

I am trying to create an app in which i am using [background serviced plugin](http://red-folder.blogspot.in/2012/09/phonegap-android-background-service.html) for uploading data to server.Then i tried to go back to the app home page when a background service will start so the user can do other work while data is uploaded. but the issue is as soon as I click on the device back button it gives an network not found error and background service stops and it navigate to another page. Then i search how to navigate to device main page using device back button using [home plugin](http://ge.tt/56OfHhm/v/0) know after starting the background service when i click on the back button it opens the device home-screen and the backgroung process continues. Can anyone tell me how to make an background serviced continue and navigate to another page.